# Pass a value from one DAG to another DAG in Apache Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have a scenario to pass the processing file names between the DAG's which is used for loading my data. Is there any functionality for the same in airflow? I hope that XCOM allows only passing file names between tasks in the same DAG.

Comment: It does; but mvce this is not, making your own answer further inscrutable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement it using below options in the operator.

python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
params={"condition_param": True, "message": "filename"},

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer?